# About PostgreSQL with Django and CPanel

Tags: django, postgresql, cpanel

**Django doesn't support earlier version of PostgreSQL, but CPanel doesn't support later version of PostgreSQL, running inspectdb makes faults. Somehow ended up with erased models.py**

I have Django (version 3.1.1)  on the server with Centos 7 with CPanel and database based on PostgreSQL (version  9.2.24). I was pretty happy with this setup, till recently I tried to do changes in my databse tables through the python models.py.

I ran the following command: python manage.py inspectdb... So I understand which changes I have to make in models.py... This command gave me the following fault:

```
# Unable to inspect table 'auth_group'
# The error was: syntax error at or near "WITH ORDINALITY"
LINE 6:                     FROM unnest(c.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY co...
```

For every table in my database. Meanwhile, I never had any problems with makemigrations or migrate commands...

So I tried to look up this fault, the only thing I found is that PostgreSQL version 9 is not supported by Django anymore...

I looked up into manage.py in my project folder and discovered that somehow it is empty, despite I have my tables in my PostgreSQL it contacts to Django and behaves normally on the site... So I would definitely need to post my tables into the file.(?)

I would like to install PostgreSQL which is supported by Django, but I have response from my host that the highest version of PostgreSQL supported by CPanel is indeed 9.2.24... And as soon as I install higher versions of PosgreSQL, I won't be able to use CPanel for my database...

Also I concerned, when I update my PostgeSQL I will erase my database and honestly it is pain in the butt to correct csv files in libreOffice excel program to load them back into database and then correct the mistakes and misunderstandings of this process...

I didn't see any information on the conflict between PostgreSQL, CPanel and Django... It might help somebody to get the information that there is some conflict between this programs, till, I guess, they get updated to support each other...Now I saw some post on a different resource, which discusses that PostgreSQL 9 is not supported by CPanel... But still no understanding how to deal with this... The source I saw, it seems it was a talk between coworkers with their own resources, which is not available to public.

What would be the best course of action to deal with this situation?

Comment: I tried to point the command like so: python manage.py inspectdb > models.py with some sort of success. Django told me that it imports all tables except it cannot do one and stuck at this point... The table's name is company. I know it is at the database, I didn't change it, it's working table. The process of importing should be the same as for other tables...

Comment: Somehow, this inspectdb command wiped out my models.py file? How it could be? I try to start my gunicorn.service and it complains: from .models import Company,... gunicorn[5014]: ImportError: cannot import name 'Company'

Comment: Ok. I think right now that, I'm going to back up the whole database (the scheme of the database) through Cpanel postresql admin... And recreate my models.py using this file... Any update I would be doing, I do them this way... using back up function instead of inspectdb which seemingly wiped out my models.py file...

Comment: hmm... I export whole database, tables or any table... It just shows empty file... Since it does that, I just copy my old back up and modify it matching as close as possible to the current database... What a trap :(

Comment: Thank you for edit. I will try to ask cleaner questions in the future. I saw some discussions for the downvotes. Saw some arguments for and against. Just want to say: We all studying here, we are doing projects, working and earning, I doubt somebody knows everything and if somebody tells he knows everything, it's quite arrogant... And if we know everything and we, as community, don't accept people who doesn't know everything, what we are doing here then, answering the questions of these dummies. They suppose to know that already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly if you are using Django 3.1.1, PostgreSQL 9.2.24 with CPanel and you cannot upgrade your PostgreSQL because you won't be able to manage your database from CPanel, because it doesn't support later versions of PostgreSQL. Don't run inspectdb on the server... Run this command in a different environment (Windows environment or Centos with GUI), change your models.py accordingly, and change this models.py on the server. Hope it helps and you won't need to run some questionable copies after you screw your models.py like I just did. If there are some opposite opinions and I didn't count something in, please let me and others know...

So generally, on the surface, the answer is simple, when you do a project do it in several environments. As I see, it is the best to do in Windows, on the virtual machine in Linux environment and as an end point version on the server. So you won't be affected too much, if and when such situations happen to you...

Ok what have I done to even the situation? Somehow I end up with wiped out models.py file. I checked, that happened, not because inspectdb, but I don't know how. It would be strange if inspectdb command would be able to erase the models.py file... But it's not possible it was empty, since my gunicorn.service never had a problem running server and databases.

I had to copy models.py file in the windows... If you look into models.py file, Python takes only the minimum needed information from database, all the rest innerworkings left for database itself. So I just copied the content of the models.py file into my server file and gunicorn.service doesn't complain anymore.

The one thing I didn't like the indexes in windows and in Linux environment become same, but I don't see how they would be copied from one environment to the other... models.py file doesn't consist such information in itself...

If I'm somehow wrong in my thoughts, please let me know.

Thank you.

Update: I end up using last version of PostgreSQL without cpanel, using psql for the all management purposes...